# Visual basic WPF load ATL C++ dll program exit when return String type

Tags: c++, vb.net, atl

I'm using VB.net WPF with `dll` made with ATL for this project
but every time I run dll function, program exit with no error
please let me know why is not working and  how to fix it.

**c++ function**

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BSTR __cdecl sprint(LPSTR str1, LPSTR str2) {
    TCHAR test[100];
    sprintf_s(test, 100, "%s %s", str1, str2);

    BSTR test2 = L"helloworld";
    return test2;
}
```

**VB.net code**

declaration

```vb
    <DllImport("database.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
    Private Shared Function sprint(ByVal str1 As String, ByVal str2 As String) As String
    End Function
```

**usage**

```vb
    Private Sub On_Submit_Btn_Clk(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        testStr = sprint("hello", "world")
        MessageBox.Show(testStr)
    End Sub
```

**issue:**

program exit when function "sprint" called.

**no issue:**

program not exit when function "sprint" return integer.

only BSTR , LPTSTR, LPSTR type returns make proram exit.

Comment: does changing `BSTR` to `char*` solve the problem?

Comment: `BSTR test2 = L"helloworld"` is always wrong. First, try to change it to `BSTR test2 = SysAllocString(L"helloworld")`;

Comment: thank you for all answer
i solve with 
```SysAllocString(L"helloworld")```
and 
```... sprint(...) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> String```
in declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In COM programming, a `BSTR` is a special `LPWSTR` which is allocated by `SysAllocString`, freed by `SysFreeString`. The characters are preceded by the string length, at offset -1. That means you can pass a `BSTR` to all functions that expect an `LPCWSTR`

`L"helloworld"` is a C++ literal, which happens to almost match the `LPWSTR` type, except for the const part. And VC++ will gloss over that last small problem. The easiest solution in MSVC is to use the `_bstr_t` wrapper type for `BSTR`, which does `SysAllocString` for you. Else you'll need to do it manually.